# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in Rest web dynamic project

Tags: java, rest

I am using a Rest web Service tutorial. I added Jersey jar files to lib folder.
Get functions works perfectly but when i use Post functions, it throws this error.

```
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [rs] in context with path [/TPWSJRS] threw exception [L''exécution de la servlet a lancé une exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonClass
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.findDeserializationType(JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java:477)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.modifyTypeByAnnotation(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:607)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:309)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._createDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:359)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._createAndCache2(StdDeserializerProvider.java:281)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:261)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider.findValueDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:119)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider.findTypedValueDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:140)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:2197)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2112)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1004)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:410)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy.readFrom(JacksonProviderProxy.java:139)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:474)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:46)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:183)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1366)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

i added this files but i have the same problem.

[image]

It is something about Jersey jar files that I didn't fix it.

here is the structure of my lib folder :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonClass` class is in the `jackson-mapper-asl` jar, so you'll have to include that as well.

Because you're manually managing dependencies, you'll keep running into issues like this. These dependencies might have their own dependencies and so on and so on. Using a tool like [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) to manage this for you is probably the way to go.

Comment: jackson-mapper-asl is included but I have the same problem

Comment: What version did you use?

Comment: i am using REST Web Service with Eclipse Neon, Tomcat 9, JAX-RS Jersey 2.24 and Jackson

Comment: Sorry. What version of jackson-mapper-asl? As an aside: this is why you want a proper build for this (like Maven or Gradle). It does all this for you and you can focus on learning the code, not how to manage dependencies.

Comment: i downloaded this :
 http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/jackson-mapper/jackson-mapper-asl.jar.zip

Comment: That's version 1.7.1. OK, this issue is getting a bit out of control. Your jackson dependencies are all different versions. Use a dependency management solution (like Maven!), or ensure they are all the same version.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem.
It is about jackson-mapper-asl file.I has version 1.7.1. I just downloaded jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13